# getIntersectedShapes in safari ipad

Tags: drag, kineticjs

I have the latest kineticjs(4.3.1) and i use hammerjs for touch events initiated within the kineticjs wrapper (div element).
I need to call getIntersectedShapes on the 'onDrag' event. After doing that and checking the drag event on an ipad i only get the dragstart event(i can't debug so i don't know if i got an error).
Doing the same action on a desktop(safari + chrome) or on iPad chrome works like a charm. only safari on iPad is a problem.
I use latest browser versions both on iPad and desktop.

Hope you can help...
thnx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code looks like but if an event is not firing and you want it to you could just do:

```
 .simulate();
```

for example:

```
 shape.simulate('dragmove');
```

do be aware, that with new kineticjs 4.3.1 and above, you should set

```
 'dragOnTop: false' //default is true
```

as an attribute for the shape if you intend to simulate drag events on it.

Let me know if that helped you out.